# Close vote count is not updated after retracting a vote

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, user-interface, retracted-close-votes

A nitpick:

- Vote to close something => "close" changes to "close (1)"
- Retract the vote => the label doesn't change back unless I reload the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an easy one. Will be fixed in next build.

Comment: You're on bug watch this week? :-)

Comment: I have been discovered! ABORT MISSION!! :-P

Comment: Wishing you a long and fruitful bug hunting watch! ;-)

Comment: You may want to check [this one](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2543/1674) also, it is for the Spanish site :)