# The automatic comment upvote is not retracted when I retract my duplicate close vote

Tags: bug, comment-voting, automatic-comments, retracted-close-votes

I've been following a duplicate proposal of another user recently, and voted to close the question, but later I changed my mind and retracted the close vote.

What bothered me is that the automatic upvote that came with my former close vote isn't automatically retracted as well, and I can't even do that manually (I know that for any regular comment upvote there's a grace period).

---

Here's what I see:

[image: Close vote options menu]

[image: Comment]

The tooltip at the comment upvote says

> You've voted for this as a useful comment.

But with my close vote retraction, it's clearly no longer the case that I find that comment useful.

Comment: Does it really matter? After all real close votes are those that count here, not up votes on CV comment.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile I do believe it matters regarding to encourage other users to either close or flag as a duplicate as well.

Comment: Maybe, if you have reason to believe that is no longer duplicate, leaving another comment stating so would carry more weight. If someone is going to mindlessly vote as duplicate based on previous voters then I don't think that one up vote more or less on CV comment will make the difference.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile _"leaving another comment stating so would carry more weight"_ I did so of course.

Comment: Well, it would be better if up vote would be automatically retracted or you could at least remove it manually. But, someone has to implement that... Right now we need SE devs fully focused on implementing more important features like thank you buttons ;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is a bug, that was [fixed four years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286774/282094); marked status-completed. It is correct to file this new report as a bug.

Comment: @Rob Sure? The question you linked is about the **close vote count**, not the **count of upvotes** appearing at the accompanied comment. My screenshots may be a bit misleading regarding that, but the close vote count was decreased correctly, but the comment upvotes were not (you can see that it shows the blue color at the comment upvotes). I suspect I can't even retract it manually, since a grace period timed out.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ They are related in that the 'live view' should follow the 'behind the scenes view' - all counts should align. Similarly "spam flags" that are retracted should "undownvote". --- The reason to add the tag "bug" is because it affects who is alerted. --- It's your question, if you want more discussion first that's OK; but you would then have more of a "support" issue, since you know we can't see the behind the scenes workings (and would have to go around closing as dupe and retracting, simply to agree with you; which I already do).

Comment: @Rob I was just unsure to file that question under the [tag:bug] tag. Will do so now. Ty.

Comment: @Rob That's *not* the same bug as the one reported here. That one has to do with the "close (x)" text in the close *button*, *not* comment upvotes.

Comment: Also, add to the question if you retracted immediately or after 5 minutes (`"later I've changed my mind"`) because you wouldn't (normally) be able to change your upvote on the comment (or edit, if your name is on it) once it times out - and that needs to be overridden to allow it (that's probably the cause). --- Similarly if you are first and no one is subsequent it should delete any autocomment the system wrote, rather than what we have currently; manual deletion (which messes it up for subsequent reviewers). In a perfect world your name would be removed and the second person's name subbed.

Answer (score 2):

This seems [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) to me.

Keep in mind that under normal circumstances, upvotes on comments can only be retracted if done within 60 seconds of the vote, and only if you haven't navigated away from the page.

Close vote retractions, on the other hand, can be done an indefinite period of time later provided the question hasn't actually been closed yet.

While it is possible to force-remove the vote in the database, I think the team implemented it this way to keep things consistent with the above restrictions. The automatic upvote isn't rendered until you refresh the page, which counts as "navigating away" from the page for the above check.

Comment: I well know that, check the comments.

Comment: Also I once told you to respect my edits to be intentional. I marked that as bug, because I think it is one, don't retag again please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Next time, in addition to retagging your question, please also rephrase your question so it actually fits the format of the tag. Your question was still phrased as a support question despite the retagging, which means that the [tag:support] tag was more relevant to it.

Comment: _"I think the team implemented it this way to keep things consistent with the above restrictions."_ Well, as @Rob pointed out in their [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350869/the-automatic-comment-upvote-is-not-retracted-when-i-retract-my-duplicate-close#comment1174800_350869): _"- all counts should align. Similarly "spam flags" that are retracted should "undownvote". ---"_